# Animating textbox text bound to a double property on property value change

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'd like to animate the transition from the old to the new value as seen in many software, i.e. when the value of the bound property changes, I'd like to increase or decrease the text of the text box by a specific offset until it reaches the new value. As an example:

Initial value: 26.0%
New value: 43.5%

Animation:
26.5% -> 30.0% -> 30.5% ....... -> 43.4

Is it possible to do this with the standard equipment of .Net or do you need a custom control?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A straightforward approach would be a custom control with a dependency property. In the PropertyChangedCallback of that property, start an animation of the visual representation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't know if .NET has a custom control. But you can do it very easily with special supervision.

1. Step One : Create a timer
2. Step Two : Run timer1 object in form load event [timerName.Start();]
3. Step Three : Create a global variable to control the second. The local variable
4. Step Four : Check textbox contents by performing a second check on the tick event of the Timer object

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   timer1.Start();
   }

   ```
   private int elapsed;

   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       elapsed = elapsed + 1;

       if (elapsed == 15)
       {
           textBox1.Text = "%" + "next value 1";
       }

       if (elapsed == 30)
       {
           textBox1.Text = "%" + "next value 2";
       }

       if (elapsed == 45)
       {
           textBox1.Text = "%" + "next value 3";
       }
   }
   ```

I hope I could help. If I can't help you, please write it down. Good coding!

Comment: A Timer might be valid approach. There is however a lot to improve here. The question is about WPF, so you you would use a DispatcherTimer. There is no Form.Load event. There is no need for a global variable. Incrementing a counter and then checking for specific values like 15, 30 etc. is pointless. Better increase the timer interval and do something reasonable on each Tick event invocation.

Comment: I hadn't seen the WPF tag. Thank you for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

An example of an auxiliary proxy for a discrete animation of a Double number:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace Proxy
{
    public partial class DeltaNumberAnimator : Freezable
    {
        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace Proxy
{
    public partial class DeltaNumberAnimator
    {

        /// <summary>Source of number</summary>
        public double Source
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(SourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="Source"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Source), typeof(double), typeof(DeltaNumberAnimator), new PropertyMetadata(0d, (d, e) => ((DeltaNumberAnimator)d).SourceChanged(e)));


        /// <summary>Number with animated change</summary>
        public double Number
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(NumberProperty);
            private set => SetValue(NumberPropertyKey, value);
        }

        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey NumberPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(Number), typeof(double), typeof(DeltaNumberAnimator), new PropertyMetadata(0d, NumberChanged));

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="Number"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberProperty = NumberPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;


        /// <summary>Sets the delta value for a discrete change in the <see cref="Number"/> property.</summary>
        public double Delta
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(DeltaProperty);
            set => SetValue(DeltaProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="Delta"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DeltaProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Delta), typeof(double), typeof(DeltaNumberAnimator), new PropertyMetadata(0.01, DeltaChanged, CoerceDelta));

        /// <summary>Number increment interval. </summary>
        public TimeSpan Interval
        {
            get => (TimeSpan)GetValue(IntervalProperty);
            set => SetValue(IntervalProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="Interval"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IntervalProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Interval), typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(DeltaNumberAnimator), new PropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.Zero, IntervalChanged));


        /// <summary>Animation in progress.</summary>
        public bool IsAnimation
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsAnimationProperty);
            private set => SetValue(IsAnimationPropertyKey, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsAnimationPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(IsAnimation), typeof(bool), typeof(DeltaNumberAnimator), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="IsAnimation"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAnimationProperty = IsAnimationPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Proxy
{
    public partial class DeltaNumberAnimator
    {

        private readonly DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        private double source;
        private double delta;
        private double number;

        public DeltaNumberAnimator()
        {
            timer.Tick += OnTick;
        }

        private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (NextStep())
            {
                timer.Stop();
                IsAnimation = false;
            }
        }

        private static void IntervalChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((DeltaNumberAnimator)d).timer.Interval = (TimeSpan)e.NewValue;
        }

        private void SourceChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            source = (double)e.NewValue;
            if (source == number)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                IsAnimation = false;
                return;
            }

            if (timer.Interval == TimeSpan.Zero ||
                delta == 0d)
            {
                Number = source;
                timer.Stop();
                IsAnimation = false;
                return;
            }
            if (!NextStep())
            {
                timer.Start();
                IsAnimation = true;
            }
        }

        // Changing Number by Delta towards Source.
        // Returns true if the Source value is reached.
        private bool NextStep()
        {
            if (number < source)
            {
                double next = number + delta;
                if (next >= source)
                {
                    Number = source;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Number = next;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                double next = number - delta;
                if (next <= source)
                {
                    Number = source;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Number = next;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }


        private static object CoerceDelta(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
        {
            double num = (double)baseValue;

            if (num < double.Epsilon && num > -double.Epsilon)
                return 0d;

            if (num > 0)
                return baseValue;
            return -num;
        }

        private static void DeltaChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((DeltaNumberAnimator)d).delta = (double)e.NewValue;
        }

        private static void NumberChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((DeltaNumberAnimator)d).number = (double)e.NewValue;
        }

    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```cs
namespace DeltaNumber
{
    public class ViewModel
    {

        public double NumberProperty { get; set; }

    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="DeltaNumber.DeltaNumberTestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DeltaNumber" xmlns:proxy="clr-namespace:Proxy;assembly=Common"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DeltaNumberTestWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
    <UniformGrid Columns="1">
        <FrameworkElement.Resources>
            <proxy:DeltaNumberAnimator x:Key="deltaAnimator"
                                       Source="{Binding NumberProperty}"
                                       Delta="1"
                                       Interval="0:0:1"/>
        </FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, Source={StaticResource deltaAnimator}}">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnimation, Source={StaticResource deltaAnimator}}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding NumberProperty}"/>
        <TextBox Text="Any text. Used only to lose focus in an binded TextBox."/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```